# What is the significance of the imaginary unit in Deutsch gate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

[image]

What is the significance of the imaginary unit $i$ in Deutsch gate? Is this controlled $R_x(\pi\alpha)$ still universal without the imaginary unit $i$?

Comment: This is missing sufficient context to make it a useful and answerable context.

Comment: While it could be improved with more context, I don't think someone with the knowledge required to answer the question will need it. (The question is quite clear to me. I don't know the answer.)

Comment: One point is that $(iR_x(\beta))(iR_x(\gamma))=-R_x(\beta+\gamma)$, i.e., by starting with $iR_x$, we can also obtain rotations $R_x$, but not vice versa. The version with an $i$ is thus more powerful. This does of course not mean that the version without an $i$ is not universal.

Answer (score 1):

In http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9505016 (see also http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9505018), it is shown that any doubly-controlled rotation (as in the question) with a rotation
$$
R=\left(\begin{matrix} e^{i\alpha}\cos\theta & -ie^{i(\alpha-\phi)}\sin\theta \\
-ie^{i(\alpha+\phi)}\sin\theta & e^{i\alpha}\cos\theta 
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
is universal as long as $\alpha$, $\phi$, and $\theta$ are irrational multiples of $\pi$ and of each other.  Thus, the specific choice $i$ of the prefactor in the Deutsch gate bears no relevance.

Note, however, that there are cases where not all angles are irrational which are nevertheless universal, such as for instance the Deutsch gate itself; it is therefore not clear whether simply omitting the $i$ above renders the gate non-universal.  (Thus, this should only be considered a partial answer.)